# What's the shortcut to toggle hexadecimal display in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, hex, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

In Visual Studio (any version), what is the shortcut to toggle hexadecimal display while debugging?

I was not able to find anything for far...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't one set by default but you can add one in the options menu.

Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard - (in 2012/2013 you can press ctrl-q to focus the "Quick Launch" box, then type "hotkeys" and press enter).

In the "Show commands containing:" textbox type "hexadecimal".

The first result should be "Debug.HexadecimalDisplay", this is the toggle for turning hexadecimal display on/off so you can then set any shortcut keys you wish - I use ctrl-h, ctrl-x.